# playing multiple videos simultaneously with sound in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

Is it possible to play multiple videos simultaneously in Android ? one of the videos could be larger while the others in thumbnail but still playing content and then selecting the thumbnail video would enlarge that while reducing the main playing video to a thumbnail.

Regards

Comment: I never see this type in youtube.apk also.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that.
I think you must play with multiple SurfaceViews(video render) and AudioTracks(audio render) yourself.